# How to filter record from multilevel document as per user input using MongoDB and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to fetch the data from multilevel document from MongoDB using aggregate function as per user input but not getting the result as expected. I am providing the format of document below.

```
{
    "zone_list":[{
        "zone":'NORTH',
        "state_list":[{
            "state":"DELHI",
            "location_list":[{
                "location":"NEW DELHI",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229853"
                },{
                   "login_id":"9937229854" 
                }]
            },{
                "location":"AIRPORT",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229855"
                }]
            }]
        },{
           "state":"JK",
            "location_list":[{
                "location":"NEW JK",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229856"
                },{
                   "login_id":"9937229857" 
                }]
            },{
                "location":"AIRPORT JK",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229858"
                }]
            }] 
        }]
    },{
        "zone":'EAST',
        "state_list":[{
            "state":"WB",
            "location_list":[{
                "location":"KOLKATA",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229859"
                },{
                   "login_id":"9937229850" 
                }]
            },{
                "location":"ASAM",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229895"
                }]
            }]
        },{
           "state":"ODISHA",
            "location_list":[{
                "location":"BHUBANESWAR",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229844"
                },{
                   "login_id":"9937229845" 
                }]
            },{
                "location":"AIRPORT BBSR",
                "task_list":[{
                    "login_id":"9937229846"
                }]
            }] 
        }]
    }]
}
```

The above is my inserted docs in database. Here I need to filter the data by matching the zone,state and location. Let's say user has input `zone='NORTH' and state='DELHI' and location='AIRPORT'` so accordingly the corresponding record should fetched. I am using the below query but did not find the expected output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{}},
    {$unwind:"$zone_list"},
    {$unwind:"$state_list"},
    {$match:{zone:zoneInput,state:stateInput}}])
    .toArray((err,docs)=>{
        if (!err) {
            res.send(docs);
        }
})
```

Here I am getting the blank output. I need if user is giving the `zone,state and location` as input the respective result will be retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `state_list` is nested inside `zone_list` so second `$unwind` is the problem here, try:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$zone_list"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$zone_list.state_list"
    },
    {
        $match: {
            "zone_list.zone": "NORTH",
            "zone_list.state_list.state": "DELHI",
            "zone_list.state_list.location_list.location": "AIRPORT"            
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: record is coming but multiple location are coming.

Comment: Location could not filter.

Comment: @satya try to take a look here https://mongoplayground.net/p/UsnHEsPVZti

Comment: yes but I could not know why I am getting the multiple location data.

Comment: `allction.collection.aggregate([ 
 {$match:{}},
 {$unwind:"$zone_list"},
 {$unwind:"$zone_list.state_list"},
 {$match: {
            "zone_list.zone": zoneInput,
            "zone_list.state_list.state": stateInput,
            "zone_list.state_list.location_list.location": locationInput            
    }}
 ])
 .toArray((err,docs)=>{
  if (!err) {
   res.send(docs);
  }
 })` this is my code.

Comment: @satya you will be getting multiple documents because of $unwinds, try to remove them

Comment: which `unwind` i have to remove.

Comment: @satya every unwind "duplicates" the data for every item in unwound array so you can have https://mongoplayground.net/p/vgz0uXKWfiJ and this will return only one document

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187051/discussion-between-satya-and-mickl).